# MATLAB: summing out one variable in equation

Tags: matlab

I have the variables 
`X = 1x20 vector of doubles
i = 0:M 
j = 0:M`
And the equation
`sum n=1 to length(X) : (X(n)^(i+j))` 

Is there a way to obtain an MxM matrix (through the indices i,j) while summing out n in each cell? I tried this with symsum but it doesn't allow indexing with n. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reshaping `X` to a vector of size `[1 x 1 x 20]` and using [implicit expansion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) a 3D `[M+1 x M+1 x 20]` array is created then by summing along the third dimension the result can be obtained.

```
X = rand(1,20);
M = 30;
ii = 0:M;
jj = (0:M).';

Y = reshape(X,1,1,[]);
result = sum(Y.^(ii+jj), 3);
```

However as the expression `Y.^(ii+jj)` creates a 3D `[M+1 x M+1 x 20]` array it may need a large amount of memory that leads to decreased performance.

We know that `x^(i+j)` can be written as `x^i * x^j` So the expression can be written as:

```
result = sum(Y.^ii .* Y.^jj,3);
```

It has the same memory consumption as the previous method. But when we reach an expression that contains sum of products we should think about converting it to very fast *matrix multiplication* :

```
Z = X .^ jj;      % A [M+1 x 20] matrix is created(implicit expansion)
result = Z * Z.'  % multiply Z by its transpose
```

So the same result is obtained without the complexity of the other solutions.

Comment: Genius, my current solution had 3 for loops... thanks

Comment: Happy to help.!